# how to load property name from existing lo4j2.xml programmatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Is there any way to programmatically get the `properties` configured in log4j2.xml.
Eg: I'd like to get the value of basePath property mentioned in the below sample file:

```
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">C:/Users/App/logs
        </Property>
    </Properties>
<Appenders>
.
.
.
</Appenders>
```

I checked the Configuration object, but couldn't find anything. Here's a sample code:

```
public static void initLogFile(String path, Level level) {
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
}
```

Is there anyway I can get this property? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> properties = config.getProperties();
String basePath = properties.get("basePath")
```

?